# why the top widget in custom scroll view doesn't scroll

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview, custom-scrolling, customscrollview

I'm trying to use custom scroll view and the slivers are a container that have a pic and gridview  when I try to scroll down or up just the list view is moving and the container does not
this is my code

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sakani/widgets/custom_drawer.dart';
import '../constants.dart';
import '../widgets/image_cards_builder.dart';

class PrevieView extends StatelessWidget {
  const PrevieView(
      {super.key,
      this.image =
          'https://pixabay.com/get/g51daa7c1a20cacfc574784d56c3469abfded36001c2f72ff520117208a0abe9e72494947fd76dc5951821b35d694226c983e329c693ddb34b672cd2565b1f343_1280.jpg'});
  static String id = 'Previeview';
  final String image;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text(kPrimaryAppName),
          elevation: 0,
          foregroundColor: Colors.black,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
        drawer: CustomDrawer(),
        body: CustomScrollView(
          scrollBehavior: MaterialScrollBehavior(),
          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          slivers: [
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Image.network(
                  image,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: ImagesBuilder(),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
} `
```

Comment: Make sure your slivers height is larger than viewport

Comment: It will also help if you show us what you are doing in CustomScrollView

Comment: this code show the CustomScrollView that has a image.network and a imageBuilder widget that build a gird of pictures